# Stuck on Motherboard splash screen

Tags: boot, usb, motherboard, splash

I have a Desktop with config as below ;
Windows-7 64bit and Linux Mint 64bit dual boot,4GB DDR2 Ram, Interl DualCore 2.5Ghz Processor,Mercury Motherboard
**Problem**
PC stuck in Motherboard splash screen **only if my Android phone connected via USB Cable**. I have no issues with plugged-in Pen-drives. Please suggest the solution.
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Your computer is most likely set to try booting from USB devices before booting from your hard drive. Since your phone is plugged in and is not bootable, your computer gets stuck.

You can either turn off booting from USB devices entirely, or change the boot order so your computer looks at the hard drives first.

Accessing the BIOS settings is usually done by pressing Delete or F2 (or some other key)while your computer boots. Once in you should be able to find a place to change the settings I mentioned before.

Comment: Currently my boot preferences are like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILJUc.jpg).
But, when I try to access the boot menu (by pressing **Esc** key) its just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHAkg.jpg) 

What should I do ?

Comment: Look in the section `Hard disk boot priority`, the second one in your first image. Probably there you have `Removable devices` upper than your hard drive

Comment: No, There HDD is at the first place

Comment: When you access the boot menu with your phone plugged in, and you select "Hard Disk", does it boot normally? Also, can you post an image of the screen your PC gets stuck in when you have the phone plugged in?

Comment: @wysiwyg I couldn't acces my **Boot Menu** (Pressing **Esc**) while phone plugged in. If I remove the connection at that splash screen moment ( [this is the splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FGtM.jpg)) the boot menu turn into specific menu like **Boot Menu** or **BIOS Menu**

Comment: I would suggest checking if there is an update to your BIOS firmware and flashing it. It's usually pretty straightforward but be sure you know what you're doing because if you mess up it can render your computer unbootable.

Answer (score -1):

Now I see that "Disable booting from USB devices in the BIOS." did not help.  If there are any settings related to USB keyboard or "legacy USB device", try changing those.

Comment: You should provide more specifics

Comment: [my bios settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILJUc.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, you already disabled them and put hard drive at #1 priority, so that's not the problem.  You might have some settings about "Compatibility with legacy USB devices" that you could disable.  If you have a link to the motherboard manual, we could be more specific.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't found any user manual for my **mercury pig31u** MB